# Dynamically altering value of a textbox

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, css

Using Rails, I am building a new wiki system from scratch; however, I am unsure how to handle the buttons for the "create a page" section. Where, for example, a person were to press the "bold" button, it would dynamically add  to the textbox below.

In theory, It should be a matter of using javascript to, "on click", add to the value of the textbox. I just do not know how to do this.

Please keep in mind that I am using ruby on rails, and I am not well versed in Javascript.

Comment: @apneadiving agreed - it made me remember that i have b&w one to set on gravatar too ;)

Comment: hahaha! Yeah it is really nice. Sadly, I cannot claim its creation. It was created by an artist on deviantart. His name is Schmault and he gave me permission to make it my logo so long as I always give him credit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your usage, I would recommend using something like TinyMCE, since it's a full-fledged javascript text editor that can be easily added to existing forms.

Generally, to append a text you just do somethig like:

```
document.getElementById('textbox').value += "something";
```

Transforming is done by getting .value and changing it to your likes.

Comment: I see. I will look into TinyMCE first.